# Qt: How to set QSpinBox/QDoubleSpinBox to angular values?

Tags: qt, pyqt

QSpinBox/QDoubleSpinBox has default of decimal value. Is it possible to change decimal to angular?

UPDATE> Please see the picture. This is the effect i want to get in QSpinBox/QDoubleSpinBox.

[image]

Comment: Radians or degrees?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Yes. How to set the QSpinBox from decimal to radian/degree values, that is my question.

Comment: I have to admit I have never heard of an angular number system, I've used binary, octal, decimal and hexadecimal, and I've heard of cultures that were big on duodecimal and sexagesimal, but I haven't heard of angular, nor can I find any info on it on the internet.

Comment: Sarcasm aside, this is a great example of why scientific nomenclature is important in concrete science, as without a proper one things make no sense, which this question is a great example of.

Comment: @dtech In Excel it is not difficult to input angular values. Thus I ask how to do in Qt.

Comment: @dtech Is it english?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/angular

Comment: @LucasMeier - and how exactly is an "angular value" different from a common number? Do you mean converting between degrees and radians or what? "Angular" means "angle" and there is a bunch of ways to express angle values using different combinations of angle units and numeral systems, fractions and whatnot.

Comment: @dtech Please see my update above. My english is not good.

Comment: I think you should employ three spin boxes horizontally arrayed  in a nice frame. And put `°`, `'`, `''` labels beside each one. Also, set the maximum values accordingly (360, 60, 60 , respectively).

Comment: @dtech. Why did you interpret this as asking for geographic coordinates? That would surely require *two* spin-boxes: one for latitude and one for longitude, with each having a specific range of values (0-90 and 0-180) as well as a direction indicator (NS and EW). The OPs image gives no suggestion of that: it's just a generic degrees, minutes and seconds representation of a plane angle.

Comment: @ekhumoro you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Just override `valueFromText`, `textFromValue` and `validate` (optionally `fixup`).

- `textFromValue` should be easy
- `valueFromText` and `validate` requires a parsing functionality, so extract common method for it.
- `fixup` use only if you know how to correct user mistakes and when `validate` returns [QValidator::Intermediate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html#State-enum) in some cases.

See [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#valueFromText).

Here is my solution C++11:

```
#ifndef DEGREESPINBOX_H
#define DEGREESPINBOX_H

#include <QDoubleSpinBox>

class DegreeSpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QDoubleSpinBox::QDoubleSpinBox;

    QString textFromValue(double value) const override;
    double valueFromText(const QString &text) const override;
    QValidator::State validate(QString &text, int &pos) const override;

private:
    static void extractDegMinSecFrom(double value,
                                     int *degrees,
                                     int *minutes,
                                     double *seconds);

    static bool parse(QString str, double *result);
    static bool areSeparatorsValid(QChar deg, QChar min, QChar sec);
};

#endif // DEGREESPINBOX_H
```

cpp file

```
#include "degreespinbox.h"
#include <QTextStream>
#include <cmath>

QString DegreeSpinBox::textFromValue(double value) const {
    int degrees, minutes;
    double seconds;
    extractDegMinSecFrom(value, &degrees, &minutes, &seconds);
    return QString(tr("%1° %2′ %3″"))
            .arg(degrees).arg(minutes).arg(seconds);
}

double DegreeSpinBox::valueFromText(const QString &text) const {
    double result = 0;
    auto ok = parse(text, &result);
    Q_ASSERT(ok);
    return result;
}

QValidator::State DegreeSpinBox::validate(QString &text, int &pos) const {
    Q_UNUSED(pos)
    return parse(text, nullptr) ? QValidator::Acceptable : QValidator::Invalid;
}

void DegreeSpinBox::extractDegMinSecFrom(double value,
                                         int *degrees,
                                         int *minutes,
                                         double *seconds) {
    Q_ASSERT(degrees);
    Q_ASSERT(minutes);
    Q_ASSERT(seconds);
    double degreesDouble;
    double minutesDouble = std::modf(value, &degreesDouble) * 60;
    *degrees = static_cast<int>(degreesDouble);
    *seconds = std::modf(minutesDouble, &minutesDouble) * 60;
    *minutes = static_cast<int>(minutesDouble);
}

bool DegreeSpinBox::parse(QString str, double *result) {
    QTextStream stream(&str);

    int degrees(0), minutes(0);
    double seconds(0);
    // %1° %2′ %3″"
    QChar symbolDegree(0), symbolMinutes(0), symbolSeconds(0);
    stream >> degrees >> symbolDegree
            >> ws >> minutes >> symbolMinutes
            >> ws >> seconds >> symbolSeconds;

    bool success = stream.status() == QTextStream::Ok
            && areSeparatorsValid(symbolDegree, symbolMinutes, symbolSeconds)
            && minutes >=0 && minutes < 60
            && seconds >=0 && seconds < 60;

    if (success && result) {
        *result = (seconds / 60.0 + minutes) / 60.0 + degrees;
    }
    return success;
}


bool DegreeSpinBox::areSeparatorsValid(QChar deg, QChar min, QChar sec) {
    return deg == QChar(L'°')
            && min == QChar(L'′')
            && sec == QChar(L'″');
}
```

Comment: So, what `int` or `double` value the `valueFromText` override is supposed to return for this text: *180° 45' 20''*?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o well 64 bit reals have plenty of resolution. A clamped 0 to 1 value can represent an entire range, so a coordinate in the center of the coordinate system will be at 0.5x0.5, from then on you can convert that to whatever combination of units you want by calculating quotients and reminders. 180° 45' 20'' would be 0.502098765.

Comment: Also, a 64 bit real, having 53 bits of precision, will provide about *7 billion times* more resolution than the  ° ' '' format using integers.

Comment: "nice" I've provided fully working code (I've tested that) and somebody did vote me down without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First - using a single spin box to manipulate such a value is not applicable, because it represents a significant range. A dedicated spin box for every component would be much easier from a user experience standpoint.

Second - if you still insist on a single spinbox, Qt doesn't have a widget that can do that out of the box. You can however easily extend on `QDoubleSpinBox` and overload the `textFromValue()` method, which is the one that determines what text the spin box is showing, and then you can compose a string value from whatever raw data you have to represent the location.

Comment: I think that it is not necessary to have 3 QSpinBox, with one it is sufficient since if the minute hand is incremented the spinbox of degrees must be affected, and so with each other. It should be similar to QDateTimeEdit.

Comment: @eyllanesc you mean to reach 1 degree the user must spin 60 times?

Comment: @eyllanesc for me QDateTimeEdit is not a "spin box" - it is a line edit that drops down a calendar. "modern" multi-component controls all have dedicated control for every component. It just makes sense. There is a bunch of ways this could be done, but it looks like they are all outside of the reach of the OP. 3 spinboxes is his best chance and while not "great"  it is perfectly adequate from a user experience perspective.

Comment: @dtech QDateTimeEdit inherits from QAbstractSpinBox, so it's a kind of SpinBox, that's what it is currently. Obviously there are several ways to create what you want, you could create with 3 spinbox, or create a custom widget with new controls, etc.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o The QSpinBox are editable similar to a QLineEdit, so it is not mandatory to spin 60 times.

Comment: A nice way would be to make the 3 components sort-of "selectable" and have the spin box manipulate the selected one, and also support keyboard input. But again, most likely too complex for the OP.

Comment: @eyllanesc so why using a spin box in the first place?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o - it looks cooler than a dumb old line edit ;) Also, I haven't tested it, but I don't really expect going over 59 seconds to add another 1 to the minute :)

Comment: Sure, but 3 might be a bit too much for eyllanesc